# Flying Saucer Font-Weight not Displaying

Tags: java, css, swing, xhtml, flying-saucer

I've just started using Flying Saucer to display html reports that will be populated by a solution I am creating.

Essentially, I am trying to get Flying Saucer's `XHTMLPanel` to display bold, but so far have been unable. I have tried using `<b></b>` tags, as well as using `<span class="b"></span>` with `.b {font-weight:bold;}` and a couple of other methods but so far no success. Below is the trimmed java code I am currently using and the xhtml below that.

```
public class HALReportViewMain extends JFrame {

XHTMLPanel panel;
FSScrollPane scroll;

public HALReportViewMain() throws Exception{    
    panel = new XHTMLPanel();
    scroll = new FSScrollPane(panel);

    panel.setDocument(new File("C:\\Users\\rudi.kershaw\\Desktop\\Report.html"));

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(scroll);
    setSize((int)new PageFormat().getImageableWidth(), (int)new PageFormat().getImageableHeight());
    setVisible(true);        
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HALReportViewMain derp = new HALReportViewMain();
}
}
```

And the a section from the xhtml Report.html;

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {font:10px arial,sans-serif;}
    p {margin-left:5px;}
    .b {font-weight:800;display:inline;margin:0;}
    #address {position:absolute;top:0px;right:5px;text-align:right}
    #picture {position:absolute;top:85px;right:20px;height:120px;width:240px;background-color:#E6E6E6}
    .sitecontactswrapper {display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;}
    .sitecontacts {margin:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sitecontactswrapper">
        <p class="sitecontacts"><span class="b">Description: </span>Example</p>
        <p class="sitecontacts"><span class="b">Full Name/s: </span>Example</p>
        <p class="sitecontacts"><span class="b">Office Phone: </span>Example</p>
        <p class="sitecontacts"><span class="b">Mobile Phone: </span>Example</p>
        <p class="sitecontacts"><span class="b">Email Address: </span>Example</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Flying Saucer has issues with certain font variants. I changed

```
font:10px arial,sans-serif;
```

to

```
font-size:10px;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
```

The fact that I have declared font-size separately is inconsequential. I just did it to separate the issues for testing. I checked other fonts and it appears that Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif and a few others wont be made bold in the `XHTMLPanel`. Why this is I have no idea. I will report it to them directly, in case it is a bug of some description.